# Is shutil.move guaranteed to either delete or throw?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move says

> If the destination is on the current filesystem, then os.rename() is used. Otherwise, src is copied to dst using copy_function and then removed.

So in both cases, can I be sure that if the function did not throw, the source file is definitely not available anymore? Are there different guarantees concerning the host OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code of `shutil` is linked at the top of the docs.

By analysing the source:

- if the source and destination are the same, rename ("`# We might be on a case insensitive filesystem`") and return
- if source already exists, throw
- try renaming (moving within one filesystem), if succeed return
- if failed, try copying - it uses the `copy_function` and **then uses `os.unlink` to get rid of the original** (or `rmtree` if it was a directory tree - but it uses `os.unlink` inside it as well). This action is NOT in `try` block, so any exception will propagate.

---

Okay, so now we know that the "removing" is done by `os.unlink`, so to analyse its behaviour, we need to [see `os.unlink` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.unlink)... which redirect us to [`os.remove` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove). The latter provides more info as to OS-specific behaviour and exceptions:

> On Windows, attempting to remove a file that is in use causes an exception to be raised; on Unix, the directory entry is removed but the storage allocated to the file is not made available until the original file is no longer in use.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive analysis (+1) and I think I am safe to assume that and will continue with that assumption. However, I am not sure if the implementation is to be taken as a guarantee, as they might change it in future releases.

Comment: Well, it's the Python standard library. If anything, it's one of the few things that should follow the Zen of Python - including "Errors should never pass silently. / Unless explicitly silenced." + "If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea", so I don't think they will change that function in `shutil` because it works and is readable. ;) If anything, some OS-specific and implementation-specific things may happen in `os` module or its insides.